# How to run dropbox inside an existing docker container that has its own Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dropbox

I have a backup service in my docker-compose.yml file:

```
backup:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.backup
    volumes:
      - ./:/web
    depends_on:
      - web
```

It generates backups of my web app in /home/backups/ with a cron job. I would like to have access to a Dropbox folder inside that container. Then I'll change the backup destination folder to that folder.

I found that:

```
dropbox:
    image: janeczku/dropbox
    environment:
      DBOX_UID: 33
      DBOX_GID: 33
    volumes:
      - /local/directory/:/dbox/Dropbox
    restart: always
    container_name: dropbox
    network_mode: 'bridge'
```

But I don't know how to make these services work together the way I want.